# Internal Server Error while using MS Graph Site API with C#

Tags: c#, api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sites

I'm trying to search file on SharePoint using Graph API. Getting the correct result on  `Microsoft graph-explorer` but when I try with C# Getting error `Status Code: 500` `Reason Phrase:Internal Server Error`

Response Details as below:

```
{
"error": {
 "code": "System.NullReferenceException",
 "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
 "innerError": {
  "date": "2021-03-19T16:16:28",
  "request-id": "f3092cda-b813-4507-928e-7e2de84fc88f",
  "client-request-id": "f3092cda-b813-4507-928e-7e2de84fc88f"
  }
 }
}
```

C# Code I'm using

```
var searchTerm = "164377_07323_03122021_112659_TaxApp";
var headerStr = @"{{""requests"": [{{""entityTypes"": [""listItem""],""query"": {{""queryString"": ""{0}""}}}}]}}";
headerStr = string.Format(headerStr, searchTerm);
var headerJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(headerStr);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResponse.AccessToken);
var content = new StringContent(headerJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query", content).Result;
var postResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Any pointers where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code. Looks like your code is getting serialized twice. So I just removed the serialization step and it worked.

```
var searchTerm = "164377_07323_03122021_112659_TaxApp";
var headerStr = @"{{""requests"": [{{""entityTypes"": [""listItem""],""query"": {{""queryString"": ""{0}""}}}}]}}";
headerStr = string.Format(headerStr, searchTerm);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResponse.AccessToken);
var content = new StringContent(headerStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query", content).Result;
var postResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

You can always test the API requests using [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Thanks a ton Shiva. It's working now. You are life saver man.

Comment: and Fiddler is just awesome tool.